How to find two-point correlators of field strength in Maxwell theory?
I know $\langle A_\mu \rangle=0$ by Lorentz symmetry. Here the expectation values $\langle . \rangle$ are taken w.r.t. the vacuum. Taking derivatives we have $\langle F_{\mu \nu} \rangle=0$. This means that the "average" electric/magnetic fields are zero. But what about two-point functions?  $\langle F_{\mu \nu} F_{\rho \sigma} \rangle$. But if I want to calculate $\langle \vec{E}^2 \rangle$ where $\vec{E}$ is the electric field for checking uncertainty principle for example, I need these two point functions or their contractions right? But most QFT books ignore these and start talking about scattering processes. I have never seen an expression for $\langle F_{\mu \nu} F_{\rho \sigma}\rangle$ or it's contractions. How can I find these expressions  so that I can un-covariantize and verify results from quantum optics literature which is full of $\langle \vec{E}^2 \rangle$ like results but arrived at in a non-covariant fashion?

Any measurement of a correlation in EM field will necessarily break Lorentz invariance. That is why people don't much bother so much with that in quantum optics. However, it is not too difficult to formulate the basic expression is a Lorentz covariant way.

huh? since when is $\langle FF\rangle$ not gauge invariant? are you sure you're doing QED (as opposed to QCD)? in any case, the computation of $\langle FF\rangle$ is pretty standard, see e.g. eq 2.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5385

Yeah, right. My bad. But why isn't $\langle FF \rangle$ gauge invariant in QCD then? Will we have to take an extra trace or something?
